# Google Maps API: radarSeach with map bounds returning results outside

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    var request = {
        bounds: map.getBounds(),
        keyword: selected_provider //some value
    };

    service.radarSearch(request, function(results, status) {

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[i].geometry.location,
                map: map
            });
        });

    });

});
```

in some cases, results' array has some locations that which markers are printed outside the map bounds.

map.getBounds() return this:

```
oh {Da: mh, va: hh}
Da: A: -23.53883129305287 j: -23.53223111409202
va: A: -46.6811610542145 j: -46.686782964309714
```

A certain result:

```
A: -23.536062
F: -46.68732699999998
```

So, F (the longitude) is not inside the longitudes from southWest and NorthEast.

Anyone have ever seen this?

Answer (score 0):

As explained here

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8340

"Bounds used to bias results when searching for Places (optional). Both location and radius will be ignored if bounds is set. Results will not be restricted to those inside these bounds; but, results inside it will rank higher."

It doesn't make any sense for me to perform a search with bounds as parameters and the response comes with results outside the bounds. The only thing I think I can do is iterate the results array before showing them, and check if each item is inside bounds.